# Is it possible to run Junit tests parallelly?

Tags: java, junit

Can Junit be multi threaded say multiple threads trying to run different Junit tests to complete faster assuming each TestCase is mutually independent .. I could not find any configuration as such .

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to run the jUnit Test Classes parallely, you can choose jUnit test Suite. Refer: http://doc.scalatest.org/1.7/org/scalatest/junit/JUnitSuite.html